# Creating a table based on input, if input doesnt exist in db file creates a table, if exists, writes ID to it

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to make a program in Python that requests an input and if the table in the DB exists, writes to it, and if it doesn't, creates it.

Here is the existing code:

```py
connection = sqlite3.connect('AnimeScheduleSub.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()

anime_id = input('enter server id')
discord_user_id = int(input('Enter token'))

    try:
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM {}".format(anime_id))
        results = cursor.fetchall()
        print(results)
    except:
        command1 = f"""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
            {anime_id}(discord_user_id INTEGER)"""
        cursor.execute(command1)
```

Basically, what it's doing (or what I'm trying to achieve) is the try loop is meant to check if the anime_id table exists. The except loop is meant to create the table if the try loop failed.

But it doesn't work, and I have no idea why. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
    command1 = f"""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
    A{anime_id}(discord_user_id INTEGER)"""
```

Creating table name with just numbers are not supported by sql.
You should start with a letter and then use numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You should "ask" the DB if the table is there or not.
Something like the below.

```
anime_id = input('enter server id')
SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='{anime_id}';
```